# How to keep my siteminder session alive until the SSO page opened in the new window/tab is active

Tags: session, single-sign-on, siteminder

I am doing the SSO to another website through Siteminder, SAML request. When a link is clicked on my web page, it supposed to open the SSO application in the new window/tab.
Siteminder is configured to timeout the session if the user is idle for 30 mins in my website. 
But I wanted to keep the session alive even after 30 mins, if the SSO application is opened and user is actively working on that.

Can anyone give me an idea how this could be achieved? Thanks.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 0):

You can change the timeout in the policy to a longer time period

Answer (score 0):

On the target website include some element (maybe in an iframe) from the SiteMinder-protected website so that the browser will retrieve it and SiteMinder will update their session accordingly